# Reclassifying by layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3

I am trying to reclassify a DEM by using  the new Reclassify by layer tool in QGIS3. I am using the following input table:

[image]

However, as shown in below screenshot of the tool, the Minimum class value field and Maximum class value field don't show any values.

[image]

What could I have done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I refer to my other post related to this where I found a solution for my problem: [QGIS: r.reclass rules based on table values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312002/qgis-r-reclass-rules-based-on-table-values/312529#312529)
I would like to thank everyone that tried to help with this and the other post!

Answer (score 1):

Reclassify by layer is expecting you to use another vector layer's attributes rather than just a table.  It works in this situation.

I don't know whether this is a bug, an oversight or deliberate, because you can indeed add a delimited text table to the TOC with no geometry but this tool only considers actual vector layers (with geometry... which is redundant for the function... and therefore I'd have thought it would be easy for the developers to allow the use of simple tables*).  This is the source of the confusion here!

For your use-case you need `Reclassify by table` or [r.reclass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.reclass.html) from GRASS.  The first of these will require you to input the values into a blank table provided (similar to ArcGIS's dialog) but the latter will allow the use of a rules file.

*This is maybe a cause for raising a feature request or bug report

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about needing a vector atrributes rather than a delimited text table. I know I could do it with reclassify by table or r.reclass for a few files. The problem is that I would like to automate the process since I have a couple of hundred of files.

Comment: I noticed your other post on that after writing this - have a look there for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Reclassify by layer` will not work if you just provide a table as a class break. The tool requires a vector layer, and based on vector layer you can choose the minimum and maximum values.

By Providing just a table such CSV file, the minimum and maximum fields are not activated:

[image]

But if you provide vector layer, they will be activated:

[image]

So the idea is to classify a raster data based on a vector layer which enables you to select minimum an maximum fields from the attribute table.

If you want to use a table and you define the values by yourself as a break values, you need to use `Reclassify by table` tool:

[image]

If you have many rasters, you can use `Execute as Batch Process` although it will be tough work if you have hundreds of raster data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about needing a vector layer to make a table input work. Your solution using Reclassify by table requires manual inputting and that's ok for a few files. The problem is that I would like to automate the process since I have a couple of hundred of files.

Comment: Right click the tool and use `execute by batch` and I know this may not also solve the issue. But I do not expect someone will offer you a script without writing your own script.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbling over this issue. There seems to exist a more straight-forward approach as .csv files aren't recognised correctly (see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29081):

- use other file formats as classification layer (e.g. .xlsx directly or convert/save them into a different layer file format)
- opening your dataset through the Data Source Manager -> Delimited Text option